# Proof in Triangles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, fractions, area

The product of the Arithmetic mean of the length of the side of a triangle and harmonic mean of the lengths of the altitude of the triangle is equal to 2*( Area of Triangle)

Comment: A simple problem to start the new year, that's good! :)

Comment: do you mean this here

Comment: Use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altitude_(triangle)#Altitude_in_terms_of_the_sides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{a+b+c}{3}\cdot\frac{3}{\frac{1}{h_a}+\frac{1}{h_b}+\frac{1}{h_c}}=\frac{a+b+c}{\frac{a}{2S}+\frac{b}{2S}+\frac{c}{2S}}=2S$$